# sending excel file to spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I try to sending excel sheet to spring mvc controller, from where i am fetching  excel sheet data and try to insert these data in some tables.

Here is my mvc controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadorder", method =RequestMethod.POST , headers="Content-Type=multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(UploadForm uploadItem, BindingResult result) throws IOException
{



    System.out.println("checking for upload item" );
    if(uploadItem == null) {
        System.out.println("file is null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("file is not null");
    }

    System.out.println("Inside Consignment controller");


System.out.println( "jdfasdjfas;dfja"+uploadItem.getFile());
    InputStream is = uploadItem.getFile().getInputStream();

    }
```

`uploadItem` contains some data,But when i am trying to fethc it , i am getting 
NullPointerException.

**UploadForm code**:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;

public class UploadForm {

private CommonsMultipartFile file;

public CommonsMultipartFile getFile() {
return file;
}

public void setFile(CommonsMultipartFile file) {
this.file = file;
}

}
```

How can I fetch data from `uploadItem`?

Comment: when i am trying to get file name  :System.out.println( "jdfasdjfas;dfja"+uploadItem.getFile()););

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(multipartFile.getInputstream());
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
}

and scanner should close on finally part.

Comment: I can see you are using `CommonsMultipartFile`. Did you correctly configure the Apache Common Multipart infrastructure ?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta nice catch.. :-) thanks a lot problem was in configuration

Answer (score -1):

Pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>excelUploadPrototype</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <poi.version>3.16-beta1</poi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

thymleaf page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thyemleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="${message}"></p>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/uploadExcelFile">
        <input type="file" name="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" /> <input
          type="submit" value="Upload file" />
    </form>

    <div th:if="${persons!=null}">
    <table id="myTableId" dt:table="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>FirstName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="person : ${persons}">
                <td th:text="${person?.name}">Kebede</td>
                <td th:text="${person?.lastName}">Tesema</td>
                <td th:text="${person?.age}">29</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Person class:

```
package com.example.controller;

public class Person {
    String name;
    String lastName;
    double age;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public double getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(double age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

Cell class:

```
package com.example.controller;

public class MyCell {
    private String content;
    private String textColor;
    private String bgColor;
    private String textSize;
    private String textWeight;

    public MyCell() {
    }

    public MyCell(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public String getTextColor() {
        return textColor;
    }
    public void setTextColor(String textColor) {
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }
    public String getBgColor() {
        return bgColor;
    }
    public void setBgColor(String bgColor) {
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
    }
    public String getTextSize() {
        return textSize;
    }
    public void setTextSize(String textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
    }
    public String getTextWeight() {
        return textWeight;
    }
    public void setTextWeight(String textWeight) {
        this.textWeight = textWeight;
    }


}
```

Excel reading class:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@Component
public class ExcelPOIHelper {

    public Map<Integer, List<MyCell>> readExcel(String fileLocation) throws IOException {

        Map<Integer, List<MyCell>> data = new HashMap<>();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation));

        if (fileLocation.endsWith(".xls")) {
            data = readHSSFWorkbook(fis);
        } else if (fileLocation.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            data = readXSSFWorkbook(fis);
        }

        int maxNrCols = data.values().stream()
          .mapToInt(List::size)
          .max()
          .orElse(0);

        data.values().stream()
          .filter(ls -> ls.size() < maxNrCols)
          .forEach(ls -> {
              IntStream.range(ls.size(), maxNrCols)
                .forEach(i -> ls.add(new MyCell("")));
          });

        return data;
    }

    private String readCellContent(Cell cell) {
        String content;
        switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
        case STRING:
            content = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                content = cell.getDateCellValue() + "";
            } else {
                content = cell.getNumericCellValue() + "";
            }
            break;
        case BOOLEAN:
            content = cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "";
            break;
        case FORMULA:
            content = cell.getCellFormula() + "";
            break;
        default:
            content = "";
        }
        return content;
    }

    private Map<Integer, List<MyCell>> readHSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
        Map<Integer, List<MyCell>> data = new HashMap<>();
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                data.put(i, new ArrayList<>());
                if (row != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                        if (cell != null) {
                            HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();

                            MyCell myCell = new MyCell();

                            HSSFColor bgColor = cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor();
                            if (bgColor != null) {
                                short[] rgbColor = bgColor.getTriplet();
                                myCell.setBgColor("rgb(" + rgbColor[0] + "," + rgbColor[1] + "," + rgbColor[2] + ")");
                            }
                            HSSFFont font = cell.getCellStyle()
                                .getFont(workbook);
                            myCell.setTextSize(font.getFontHeightInPoints() + "");
                            if (font.getBold()) {
                                myCell.setTextWeight("bold");
                            }
                            HSSFColor textColor = font.getHSSFColor(workbook);
                            if (textColor != null) {
                                short[] rgbColor = textColor.getTriplet();
                                myCell.setTextColor("rgb(" + rgbColor[0] + "," + rgbColor[1] + "," + rgbColor[2] + ")");
                            }
                            myCell.setContent(readCellContent(cell));
                            data.get(i)
                                .add(myCell);
                        } else {
                            data.get(i)
                                .add(new MyCell(""));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (workbook != null) {
                workbook.close();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    private Map<Integer, List<MyCell>> readXSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        Map<Integer, List<MyCell>> data = new HashMap<>();
        try {

            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                data.put(i, new ArrayList<>());
                if (row != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                        if (cell != null) {
                            XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();

                            MyCell myCell = new MyCell();
                            XSSFColor bgColor = cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor();
                            if (bgColor != null) {
                                byte[] rgbColor = bgColor.getRGB();
                                myCell.setBgColor("rgb(" + (rgbColor[0] < 0 ? (rgbColor[0] + 0xff) : rgbColor[0]) + "," + (rgbColor[1] < 0 ? (rgbColor[1] + 0xff) : rgbColor[1]) + "," + (rgbColor[2] < 0 ? (rgbColor[2] + 0xff) : rgbColor[2]) + ")");
                            }
                            XSSFFont font = cellStyle.getFont();
                            myCell.setTextSize(font.getFontHeightInPoints() + "");
                            if (font.getBold()) {
                                myCell.setTextWeight("bold");
                            }
                            XSSFColor textColor = font.getXSSFColor();
                            if (textColor != null) {
                                byte[] rgbColor = textColor.getRGB();
                                myCell.setTextColor("rgb(" + (rgbColor[0] < 0 ? (rgbColor[0] + 0xff) : rgbColor[0]) + "," + (rgbColor[1] < 0 ? (rgbColor[1] + 0xff) : rgbColor[1]) + "," + (rgbColor[2] < 0 ? (rgbColor[2] + 0xff) : rgbColor[2]) + ")");
                            }
                            myCell.setContent(readCellContent(cell));
                            data.get(i)
                                .add(myCell);
                        } else {
                            data.get(i)
                                .add(new MyCell(""));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (workbook != null) {
                workbook.close();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

//@RestController
@Controller
public class ExcelController {

    private String fileLocation;

//  @Resource(name = "excelPOIHelper")
    @Autowired
    private ExcelPOIHelper excelPOIHelper;

    @PostMapping("/uploadExcelFile")
    public String uploadFile(Model model, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        if(file.getOriginalFilename().endsWith("xls")||file.getOriginalFilename().endsWith("xlsx")){
            InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
            File currDir = new File(".");
            String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
            fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + file.getOriginalFilename();
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
            int ch = 0;
            while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                f.write(ch);
            }
            f.flush();
            f.close();
            model.addAttribute("message", "File: " + file.getOriginalFilename() 
              + " has been uploaded successfully!");
        }else{
             model.addAttribute("message", "Incorrect file");
        }

        return "excel";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/readPOI")
    public String readPOI(Model model) throws IOException {

     Person person=null;
     boolean isNumber=false;
     List<Person> persons=new ArrayList<Person>();
     String regex = "[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*";
      if (fileLocation != null) {
          if (fileLocation.endsWith(".xlsx") || fileLocation.endsWith(".xls")) {
              Map<Integer, List<MyCell>> data
                = excelPOIHelper.readExcel(fileLocation);
              Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,List<MyCell>>> it=data.entrySet().iterator();
              it.next();
              while(it.hasNext()){
                  Map.Entry<Integer,List<MyCell>> row=it.next();
                      if(!row.getValue().isEmpty()){
                          person=new Person();
                          person.name=row.getValue().size()>=1?row.getValue().get(0).getContent():"";
                          person.lastName=row.getValue().size()>=2?row.getValue().get(1).getContent():"";
                          if(row.getValue().size()>=3){
                              isNumber=row.getValue().get(2).getContent().matches(regex);
                              if(isNumber){
                                  person.age=Double.parseDouble(row.getValue().get(2).getContent());
                              }else{
                                  person.age=0;
                              }

                          }

                          persons.add(person);
                      }
              }
              model.addAttribute("persons", persons);

              model.addAttribute("data", data);
          } else {
              model.addAttribute("message", "Not a valid excel file!");
          }
      } else {
          model.addAttribute("message", "File missing! Please upload an excel file.");
      }
      return "excel";
    }

    @GetMapping("/uploadExcelFile")
    public String uploadPage(Model model){
        List<Person> persons=null;
        model.addAttribute("persons",persons);
        model.addAttribute("message", "start");
        return "excel";
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is excessively broad given the narrow question, `how to fetch data from uploadItem`?